# While looping through a xml file I'm getting unexpected line break in the output

Tags: php, xml, file, foreach

The php Code even if the node does not have children, it is executing only the `<br>` part of the second foreach loop, thus output is spaces, then if the are childnodes, it output the result. Tried put an if statement before the 2nd foreach loop, still not working!

```
<?php

$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("contact.xml");

foreach ($xmlDoc->children() as $books) {
    if ($books->Firstname == "John") {
        echo $books->Firstname, "<br>";
        echo $books->Lastname, "<br>";
        echo $books->Nickname, "<br>";
        foreach ($books->children() as $book) {
            echo $book->CourseName, "<br>";
            echo $book->ID, "<br>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Result:

```
John
Cruse
Tom




Software
484887
```

^ Why do I get these extra 3 line breaks and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Show your xml file! Also show your current + expected output

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>
    <PersonalInfo>
            <Firstname>John</Firstname>
            <Lastname>Cruise</Lastname>
            <Nickname>Tom</Nickname>
            
            <Course>
                <CourseName>Software</CourseName>
                <ID>131315</ID>
                
            </Course>
        </PersonalInfo>
       </Details>

Comment: Please, please don't post code in comments! Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29999416/edit) button!

Comment: Expected output: display each result on a line.
Current output: Displaying John Cruse Tom on each line, but then leaves 3 lines then display software and iD on each line!
hope this help, am new here, not able to post xml file and picture of result!

Comment: Please edit your question, Don't only add these important additions in comments but edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your second foreach header from:

```
foreach($books->children() as $book){    
              //^^^^^^^^^^
```

to this:

```
foreach($books->Course as $book){
              //^^^^^^
```

Because with your old foreach header you looped through all child's of `PersonalInfo` which was: `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Nickname`, `Course` and only the last one (`Course`) had a CourseName and an ID in it, so the other ones just printed 2x break line tags.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooo much.. God bless.. Spent one night with this.. It works, i will mark this as answer. :)
Thanks again buddy..

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    $books->count();
It gives you count of children.
Note:
SimpleXMLElement::children() returns a node object no matter if the current node has children or not. Use count() on the return value to see if there are any children. As of PHP 5.3.0, SimpleXMLElement::count() may be used instead.

Comment: tried again  if( $books->count() > 0){//foreach loop}
not working :(

Comment: when you print the count value, what does it give you?

Comment: Its ok buddy, got the solution. Thanks anyway.. :)